# sharedpreferences wont remember values in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Here is the code where I put the values:

```
if(soundima == 1){
                        soundima=0;
                        editor.putInt("sOn", soundima);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                    else if(soundima == 0){
                        soundima=1;
                        editor.putInt("sOn", soundima);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
```

Then when I quit the application, the values are not remembered. I get the values with this code:

```
editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    soundima = editor.getInt("sOn", 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure your code goes into the good part of your `if-else` statement?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure..

Comment: Can you show us how do you create the `editor` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why that is not working. However, the following code should solve the problem.

```
//create a constant to use for the shared preferences
public static final String YOUR_CONSTANT = "Preferences";
```

Then to place the values in shared preferences, use the following code:

```
if(soundima == 1){
    soundima = 0;
    SharedPreferences sound = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONSTANT,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sound.edit();
    editor.putInt("sOn", soundima);
    editor.commit();
}
else if(soundima == 0){
    soundima = 1;
    SharedPreferences sound = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONSTANT,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sound.edit();
    editor.putInt("sOn", soundima);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then to retrieve the values, use this code:

```
SharedPreferences sound = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONSTANT,0);
soundima = sound.getInt("sOn", 0);
```